# DAX - how to convert a date string from another locale into a date type

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a date string that fails to import because it is in a different format to that expected my the machines locale (i.e. US dates to a UK machine).

How do I tell DAX to convert this string into a date, but using a specified format or locale, different to the machines default.

For example, I would like to import

3/27/2008 11:07:31 AM

as

27/3/2008 11:07:31 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

First option, use the basic `Formatting` tab functionality in Power BI.

Select the column and use the below settings in the `Formatting` tab:

[image]

Second option (**recommended**), use PowerQuery to import the text column in datetime data type.

The following expression will split the text by `"/"` character, then will convert `dd/mm/yyyy` string to the datetime data type.

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "DateTime",
 each Text.Split([#"#(001A)Date Import"],"/"){1} & "/" 
  & Text.Split([#"#(001A)Date Import"],"/"){0} & "/" &
    Text.Split([#"#     (001A)Date Import"],"/"){2})
```

In this case I've added an additional column in order to import the column in the required datetime type, you can apply the changes to the same column though.

[image]

`Date import` column is the actual text column, DateTime is the column I've added to import `Date Import`as Datetime type.

If you get stuck check the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt211003.aspx) about PowerQuery.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most practical solution is in the Query Editor, but complex formula are not required.

I would Right-click the column and choose Change Type / Using Locale.  Then I would specify Data Type = Date and Locale = English (United States).